# Laravel Breeze Vite Dev-Server Error: "cannot test case insensitive FS, CLIENT_ENTRY does not point to an existing file"

Tags: laravel, build, vite, laravel-breeze

I set up a fresh Laravel Breeze Project with Vite. When I run:

```
npm run dev
```

I get this Error:

```
failed to load config from PATH/vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
Error: cannot test case insensitive FS, CLIENT_ENTRY does not point to an existing file: PATH/dist/client/client.mjs
    at testCaseInsensitiveFS (PATH/node_modules/vite/dist/node-cjs/publicUtils.cjs:3420:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (PATH/node_modules/vite/dist/node-cjs/publicUtils.cjs:3425:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Object._require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (file:///PATH/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6b3a5aff.js:63517:17)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (PATH/node_modules/vite/index.cjs:7:31)
```

I can't find any Information about this error! A few Weeks ago I had no Problems with this.

Here is my Vite Config File:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure that your project path doesn't contain any special character like `#`.